# Как найти в строке три слова подряд?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

> Дана строка, в ней слова и цифры, разделенные пробелом. Надо найти в этой строке три слова подряд.

```
def m (words) :
    a = 0
    for w in words.split() :
        pass
        while w.isalpha() is True :
            a += 1
            if a == 3 :
                return True
            else :
                return False    # вот на этом я застрял.
```

Comment: Мой код не работает выдает False все время.

Comment: приведите исходные данные для вашего примера, на чем вы тестируете?

Comment: На IDLE тестирую. Допустим words = 'ddd ddd ddd 55 88', должно вывести True по идее а выводит False.

Comment: А если две нижние строчки убрать то выведет True

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот функция, которая делает то, что вам нужно.

```
def m (words) :
    count = 0
    for w in words.split() :
        if w.isalpha() :
            count += 1
            if count == 3 :
               return True
        else :
            count = 0

    return False    # вот на этом я застрял.
```

Функция бежит по словам в цикле. Если слово состоит из букв(функция isalpha() проверяем это), то накапливает счетчик(инкрементируем переменную), иначе сбрасывает его в ноль. 
Если счетчик накопился из трех слов, то значит мы нашли в строке 3 подряд слова.

Comment: Я бы убрал второй `if` в секцию `then` первого, чтобы избежать лишних проверок.

Comment: @kff, конечно, спасибо за совет. Так и сделал.

Answer (score 4):

Задачу можно решить, например, следующим образом:

```
def three_words(s):
    t = s.split()
    start = end = 0
    while end < len(t):
        if t[end].isalpha():
            if end - start >= 2:
                return t[start:end + 1]
            end += 1
        else:
            start = end = end + 1
```

Метод вернёт список из первых трёх встретившихся подряд слов или `None` если такой группы слов нет.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти три слова подряд  в строке и вывести их:

```py
words = text.split()
for triple in zip(words, words[1:], words[2:]):
    if all(s.isalpha() for s in triple):
        print(*triple)
        break
else: 
    print("not found")
```

Это прямолинейный для Питон-программиста код, но он выполняет ненужное копирование и сравнения.

Вот код, схожий с решением, использующим `count` из  [ответа @Alexcei Shmakov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605484/23044)—данный вариант печатает саму тройку слов, а не только есть ли она в строке, как `count` решение:

```py
triple = []
for s in text.split():
    if s.isalpha():
        triple.append(s)
        if len(triple) == 3:
            print(*triple)
            break
    else:
        del triple[:] # empty
else:
    print("not found")
```

Чтобы не создавать возможно большой список строк, разделённых пробелом, можно регулярные выражения использовать:

```py
import re

m = re.search(r'\s+'.join([r'[^\d\s]+']*3), text)
print(m.group() if m else "not found")
```

Этот вариант ищет символы, которые не являются числами, пробелами (что подходит для постановки задачи в вопросе), так как `re` модуль не поддерживает аналог [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha). [`regex` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) поддерживает `\p{Letter}`.

Измерения могут показать, есть ли разница в производительности для фактического ввода.

Answer (score 0):

Взято с сайта [py.checkio.org/ru/mission/three-words/](https://py.checkio.org/ru/mission/three-words/):

Решение №1:

```
def checkio(words):
    succ = 0
    for word in words.split():
        succ = (succ + 1)*word.isalpha()
        if succ == 3: return True
    else: return False
```

Решение №2:

```
checkio=lambda x:"www" in "".join('w' if w.isalpha() else 'd' for w in x.split())
```

Решение №3:

```
import re

def checkio(words):
    return True if re.search('\D+\s\D+\s\D+', words) else False
```